# Images not loading on web page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, hbs

I am trying to display some images on my webpage using node js express and hbs file the image is not being displayed on web page getting error GET http://localhost:3000/tempelates/P2.jpg 404 (Not Found)

.hbs code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ParkEase - Parking Management System</title>
    <style>
        /* Your CSS styles here */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .header {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 0;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .container {
            width: 90%;
            margin: 20px auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .row {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .parking-container {
            width: 30%;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            cursor: pointer; /* Add cursor style to indicate it's clickable */
        }
        .parking-container img {
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .parking-info {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .time-period {
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>ParkEase - Parking Management System</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="parking-container" onclick="promptRent('Parking 1', '1')">
                <img src="pexels-abdulwahab-alawadhi-3422964.jpg" alt="Parking 1">
                <div class="parking-info">
                    <h3>Parking spot - 1</h3>
                    <p>Parking: P1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parking-container" onclick="promptRent('Parking 2', '2')">
                <img src="/tempelates/P2.jpg" alt="Parking 2">
                <div class="parking-info">
                    <h3>Parking spot - 2</h3>
                    <p>Parking: P2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parking-container" onclick="promptRent('Parking 3', '3')">
                <img src="/tempelates/P3.jpg" alt="Parking 3">
                <div class="parking-info">
                    <h3>Parking spot - 3</h3>
                    <p>Parking: P3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function promptRent(parking, parkingSpot) {
    var vehicleNumber = prompt("Enter Vehicle Number:");
    if (vehicleNumber) {
        var daysCount = prompt("Enter the number of days for parking:");
        if (daysCount) {
            var totalCost = 100 * daysCount; // Assuming the cost per day is $100

            // Calculate rental start time (current time)
            var rentalStartTime = new Date();
            var rentalStartFormatted = formatDateTime(rentalStartTime);
            
            // Calculate rental end time by adding the specified number of days to the start time
            rentalStartTime.setDate(rentalStartTime.getDate() + parseInt(daysCount));
            var rentalEndFormatted = formatDateTime(rentalStartTime);

            // Print the receipt with rental start and end times, including the date and time
            alert("Receipt\n\nParking: " + parking + "\nVehicle Number: " + vehicleNumber + "\nParking Spot: " + parkingSpot + "\nRental Start: " + rentalStartFormatted + "\nRental End: " + rentalEndFormatted + "\nTotal Cost: $" + totalCost);
        }
    }
}

function formatDateTime(date) {
    var dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // January is 0!
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    var hours = String(date.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
    var minutes = String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
    var seconds = String(date.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');

    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

.js code -

```
const express=require("express")
const app=express()
const path=require("path")
const hbs=require("hbs")
const collection=require("./mongodb")

const tempelatePath=path.join(__dirname, '../tempelates')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../tempelates')));

app.use(express.json())
app.set("view engine", "hbs")
app.set("views", tempelatePath)
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get("/",(req, res) => {
    res.render("login")
})

app.get("/signup",(req, res) => {
    res.render("signup")
})

app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const data={
      name:req.body.name,
      password:req.body.password
  }

await collection.insertMany([data])

res.render("login")

})


app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    
  try{
      const check=await collection.findOne({name:req.body.name})

      if(check.password===req.body.password){
          res.render("home")
      }
      else{
          res.send("wrong password")
      }


  }
  catch{
    res.send("Wrong details")
  }
  
  })
  
app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log("port connected");
})
```

the three images P1.jpg P2.jpg P3.jpg is not being displayed instead icon is being displayed

tried diiferent things

Comment: It seems there might be a small issue with the way you're serving static files. I thing you're using the wrong directory name "tempelates" instead of "templates". Additionally, the file path provided for the image source might not be accurate. Here's how you can fix it:

Rename the "tempelates" folder to "templates" if that's a typo.
Ensure that your image files are placed in the "templates" directory. Tell me if this resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../tempelates')));
> ```

This tells the middleware that when you ask for `/foo/bar.baz` it should look for a file at `__dirname/../tempelates/foo/bar.baz`.

You are asking for `http://localhost:3000/tempelates/P2.jpg` so it is looking for ``__dirname/../tempelates/tempelates/P2.jpg`.

You are unlikely to be doubling up the directory there.

Presumably you either want:

- To ask for `http://localhost:3000/P2.jpg`
- To omit `templates` in the URL from the search: `app.use('/templates', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../tempelates')));`

---

Note that that isn't how you spell [templates](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/template) and that images aren't templates so that's probably not a good directory name anyway.